# Credit card readers for iPhone - Can I use it as another input device?

Tags: iphone, accessories

I need a credit card reader for an app I'm developing. Since this site is more about the hardware than the developer side, I'm looking for a hardware piece that I can buy that reads credit cards. Most of the CC readers I see on iTunes or amazon come with an app that can read them: [Square](https://squareup.com/square), [Credit Card Terminal](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/credit-card-terminal/id290137919?mt=8), [Mobile Smartphone Magstripe Reader](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0054KG11S)

Are there magnetic card readers that work with iOS that consumers / makers can experiment with?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674197/is-there-a-credit-card-reader-for-the-iphone-that-has-its-own-api

Comment: I've edited this to be on-topic here. If the OP needs API support or to know how well a piece of hardware works from a developer standpoint then Stack Overflow is the place for that. Asking about hardware compatibility is fine for this site even if it's a developer that wants to know :-)